# Can I make the hover background color of a container, larger than its parent container

Tags: html, css

Basically I am trying to achieve the hover effect as seen in the image below, but I'm not sure on how to make the background color exceed the borders of its parent container without effecting the height of the parent. I've attached a Codepen as well, thank you in advance!

[What I want to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx0zR.png)

```css
/* =============
    Base
============= */
#aspo-container {
  background-color: #F3F5FF;
  padding: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#aspo-container p {
  font-size: rem-calc(20);
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 3px solid #171838;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container div:hover {
  background-color: #171838;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container #activities {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #171838;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container #staffing {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #171838;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #171838;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container #participation {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #171838;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #171838;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container #outcomes {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #171838;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>

    <section id="aspo-container">

      <div id="aspo-inner-container">
        <div id="activities" class="active">
          <p>Activities</p>
        </div>
        <div id="staffing">
          <p>Staffing</p>
        </div>
        <div id="participation">
          <p>Participation</p>
        </div>
        <div id="outcomes">
          <p>Outcomes</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>

  </main>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the contents of your codepen to your question. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe using , transform: scale(3); helps on hover to make it bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with `padding-top` and a negative `margin-top`.

Note that I haven't tried very hard to make the example below look very nice, or look like your image, because I didn't see the point – presumably you have the code for most of it already. The snippet is just to demonstrate the method.

Hover over the text to see the effect.

```css
nav {
  height: 30px;
  width: 340px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav-option {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 6px;
  
  /* These are the important lines */
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.nav-option:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-option">Activities</div>
  <div class="nav-option">Staffing</div>
  <div class="nav-option">Participation</div>
  <div class="nav-option">Outcomes</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I ended up changing the hover scss to as follows, and it works perfectly.

    div:hover{
      background-color: #171838;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-weight: 700;
      margin: -1em 0 -1em 0;
      padding-top: 1em;
      border-radius: 5px;
      p{
        transform: scale(1.5);
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using transform property of css with scale function to make it bigger on hover e.g `transform:scale(1.5) ;`

You can adjust number in scale to make it fit whichever size is needed.

Comment: That works for the most part, but I only need it to scaleX, and if I do that is stretches the text. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can give font size to text also on hover to compensate for it? Or Nest the parent item and the text separately and scale parent item and keep text separately font size adjusted, you will have to fine tune to get it right to stop text moving...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close to what you want. I also added an animated transition, but as-is it's a bit buggy in my browser (leaves behind artifacts). The overall effect is achieved by increasing the padding the same as the negative margin.

A few notes:

- Generally you wouldn't set widths on flex children if you want them to be fluid. `flex-grow` works better.
- `p` elements aren't the best choice for menu items, both semantically and practically. Menu elements aren't usually paragraphs of text, and the default styling for `p` tags has extras you may wish to reset. So it's easier to use `div` or `span`, or the more semantic `ul`/`li` tags (although you would have to reset some of that styling also)
- Changing `font-weight` on hover is problematic for fluid width elements, as it changes the element width, which causes jitter.
- For this use case, you don't actually want any `space-between` the menu items, as you expect them to all be right next to each other.
- It is a good idea to have the container padding be big enough to contain the hovered elements.

```css
/* =============
    Base
============= */

#aspo-container {
  background-color: #F3F5FF;
  padding: 1.5em;
  justify-content: center;
}

#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 3px solid #171838;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container>div:hover {
  background-color: #171838;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: -0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container>div {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #171838;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #171838;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: rem-calc(20);
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  transition: all linear 0.25s;
}

#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container>div:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

#aspo-container #aspo-inner-container>div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <section id="aspo-container">

    <div id="aspo-inner-container">
      <div id="activities" class="active">
        Activities
      </div>
      <div id="staffing">
        Staffing
      </div>
      <div id="participation">
        Participation
      </div>
      <div id="outcomes">
        Outcomes
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

</main>
```